# Eliminate user using countdown timer

Tags: php, jquery

I have a project where if a user activates something, he has to do it before 6 hours, so as soon as the user activates the timer should start and once it gets to six hours he should be eliminated if not done. Please how do i achieve this.
I am using php and Jquery.

Comment: you can put the starting time somewhere and set a cron job or something like that

Comment: SO don't provide code writing, we help with code issues, so post the code you have so far